# Which conditions on $f$ imply compact fibers $f^{-1}(y)$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ of a smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ at any regular value $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are smooth submanifolds by the preimage theorem.

Under which conditions on $f$ are its fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ compact?

Comment: This works if $f$ is proper.

Comment: @Didier True! However, proper is just the definition of the condition above, so it is just a tautology. I would like to find sufficiency conditions for this to be true

Comment: This condition is weaker than $f$ being proper. Properness is equivalent to having compact fibers and being a closed map in this case. You can also have compact fibers and not be a closed map, e.g. consider the composition of a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\cong(-1,1)$ and the inclusion $(-1,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Euler_Salter Proper means that the preimage of a compact is compact. What you consider means that preimage of *singletons* are compact: this is not at all the same thing

Comment: @Didier ah you're right! I suppose I am just looking for some condition on $f$ that would imply that the preimage of singletons are compact

Comment: @Euler_Salter [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968571/a-characterization-of-proper-maps) is related

Answer (score 1):

You have the following characterisation of proper maps:

> A continuous map $f\colon\mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf{R}^n$ is proper if, and only if, $\lim\limits_{\|x\|\to +\infty}\|f(x)\|=+\infty$.

The condition ensures that the reverse image of bounded subsets are bounded.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @Euler_Salter This is a classical, and easy, exercise. I think with suitable tags you can find it on this website